# Chrome extension exclude_matches not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, google-chrome-extension

I have set up on my extension manifest.js to run on a url patterns, but I need also stop it on some subdoamins. I have used the excluded_matches option and if enter on the site for the excluded url it works, but if I navigate through the site, it changes dinamically the content and url by javascript (changing window.history.pushState), seem like the extension does not detect when url changes by javascript.

Is there any way to detect this url change to void/exclude run my extension?

Thnaks!

Comment: Have you tried out [Match Patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns)? E.g., something like `http://*.example.org/*`?

Comment: What's your match patterns for content scripts? And basically you could listen to [`webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onHistoryStateUpdated)